# Handler logic in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, timer, handler, delay

Below is the code I'm using in a handler in order to create a separate thread.
I have a list which stores all the Squares and I only want 10 to display (for testing purposes) using .size() to get the number of squares on the list.

The idea is to randomly generate x and y values and then .addSquare would add it to the list but also draw on my Canvas.

My question is, how would I delay the time of each individual square draws so that all 10 does not appear at the same time?

EDIT: By that, I mean, displaying each individual one with a delay.

Thanks.

```
handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (sModel.getSquares().size() < 10 )
            {
                int width = 980;
                int height = 1280;

                // create random
                Random rand = new Random();

                // float values for storing random x, y coords
                float randX, randY;

                randX = rand.nextInt(width); // random x
                randY = rand.nextInt(height); // random y
                sModel.addSquare(randX, randY, Color.BLUE);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
            }
        }
    };handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);
```

**EDIT:** LogCat as requested: (errors from trying to implement wait() and notify())

```
01-15 07:22:47.811: W/asset(3951): Copying FileAsset 0x6a1eeb58 (zip:/data/app/ce0941a.coursework.Int.BoxesGame-1.apk:/resources.arsc) to buffer size 5184 to make it aligned.
01-15 07:22:47.901: I/Adreno-EGL(3951): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:316>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL3907963)
01-15 07:22:47.901: I/Adreno-EGL(3951): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.09
01-15 07:22:47.901: I/Adreno-EGL(3951): Build Date: 09/26/13 Thu
01-15 07:22:47.901: I/Adreno-EGL(3951): Local Branch: 
01-15 07:22:47.901: I/Adreno-EGL(3951): Remote Branch: 
01-15 07:22:47.901: I/Adreno-EGL(3951): Local Patches: 
01-15 07:22:47.901: I/Adreno-EGL(3951): Reconstruct Branch: 
01-15 07:22:47.991: D/qdmemalloc(3951): ion: Mapped buf base:0x6c932000 size:8355840 offset:0 fd:54
01-15 07:22:48.001: D/qdmemalloc(3951): ion: Mapped buf base:0x6c874000 size:4096 offset:0 fd:55
01-15 07:22:52.526: D/qdmemalloc(3951): ion: Mapped buf base:0x6d26d000 size:8355840 offset:0 fd:57
01-15 07:22:52.526: D/qdmemalloc(3951): ion: Mapped buf base:0x6c886000 size:4096 offset:0 fd:58
01-15 07:22:52.636: D/qdmemalloc(3951): ion: Mapped buf base:0x6da65000 size:8355840 offset:0 fd:59
01-15 07:22:52.636: D/qdmemalloc(3951): ion: Mapped buf base:0x6c887000 size:4096 offset:0 fd:60
01-15 07:22:52.636: W/dalvikvm(3951): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415d4970)
01-15 07:22:52.636: E/AndroidRuntime(3951): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-15 07:22:52.636: E/AndroidRuntime(3951): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{ce0941a.coursework.Int.BoxesGame/ce0941a.coursework.controller.GameActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class ce0941a.coursework.controller.GameActivity; no empty constructor
01-15 07:22:52.636: E/AndroidRuntime(3951):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2435)
01-15 07:22:52.636: E/AndroidRuntime(3951):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2574)
01-15 07:22:52.636: E/AndroidRuntime(3951):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
01-15 07:22:52.636: E/AndroidRuntime(3951):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1413)
01-15 07:22:52.636: E/AndroidRuntime(3951):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-15 07:22:52.636: E/AndroidRuntime(3951):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
01-15 07:22:52.636: E/AndroidRuntime(3951):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5789)
01-15 07:22:52.636: E/AndroidRuntime(3951):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-15 07:22:52.636: E/AndroidRuntime(3951):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-15 07:22:52.636: E/AndroidRuntime(3951):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
01-15 07:22:52.636: E/AndroidRuntime(3951):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:843)
01-15 07:22:52.636: E/AndroidRuntime(3951):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-15 07:22:52.636: E/AndroidRuntime(3951): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class ce0941a.coursework.controller.GameActivity; no empty constructor
01-15 07:22:52.636: E/AndroidRuntime(3951):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
01-15 07:22:52.636: E/AndroidRuntime(3951):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
01-15 07:22:52.636: E/AndroidRuntime(3951):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
01-15 07:22:52.636: E/AndroidRuntime(3951):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
01-15 07:22:52.636: E/AndroidRuntime(3951):     ... 11 more
01-15 07:22:59.263: D/Process(3951): killProcess, pid=3951
01-15 07:22:59.263: D/Process(3951): com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException:123 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:693 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:690
```

Comment: You could call wait on the current thread and call notifyAll after say 10 sec

Comment: @Karan_Rana I'm pretty new to Android programming, could you please provide an example? Thanks.

Comment: http://www.journaldev.com/1037/java-thread-wait-notify-and-notifyall-example

this link might clear your Thread concepts

Comment: I tried that, but the app crashes. /:

Comment: could you please post the log cat trace

Answer (score 1):

You have implemented a constructor for your activity remove that and put it's code in `onCreate`.

This error has nothing to do with handler.

Comment: the LogCat was posted after I tried the suggestion from Karan_Rana to show my implementation of wait() and notify() to show my errors when it didn't work.

There is no error with the code, it runs fine.
I need to delay the time it takes for the square to be drawn within the handler.
Any suggestions?
Many thanks.